# Why is may arrayList only showing one String?

Tags: java, string, printing, arraylist

```
java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Sites 
{
    String country2, city2;
    int days2, count = 0, time = 10;
    double rate2, scost = 0;

    public Sites(String province, String city, int days, double rate)
    {
        country2 = province;
        city2 = city;
        days2 = days;
        rate2 = rate;
    }

    public void Sites() 
    {
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            try
            {
                while(count == 0)
                {
                    BufferedReader file2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("Sites.txt"));
                    while(file2.ready())
                    {
                        String cityS = file2.readLine();

                        String site1 = file2.readLine();
                        String cost1 = file2.readLine();
                        double cost1a = Double.parseDouble(cost1);
                        double tcost1 = cost1a * rate2;

                        String site2 = file2.readLine();
                        String cost2 = file2.readLine();
                        double cost2a = Double.parseDouble(cost2);
                        double tcost2 = cost2a * rate2;

                        String site3 = file2.readLine();
                        String cost3 = file2.readLine();
                        double cost3a = Double.parseDouble(cost3);
                        double tcost3 = cost3a * rate2;

                        String wiggle = file2.readLine();

                        if (cityS.equalsIgnoreCase(city2))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Province/Territory: " + country2 + "Number of Days Left: " + days2);
                            System.out.println("City: " + city2 + "Time: " + time + ":00");

                            System.out.println("");

                            System.out.println("Where would you like to go?");
                            System.out.println("1)" + site1);
                            System.out.println("Cost) " +cost1 );
                            System.out.println("");

                            System.out.println("2)" + site2);
                            System.out.println("Cost) " +cost2 );
                            System.out.println("");

                            System.out.println("3)" + site3);
                            System.out.println("Cost) " +cost3 );
                            System.out.println("");

                            System.out.println("4)Eat");
                            System.out.println("Cost) 25 ");
                            System.out.println("");

                            System.out.println("5)Rest");
                            System.out.println("Cost) 0 ");
                            System.out.println("");

                            int answer = scan.nextInt();

                            ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

                            Eat food = new Eat(answer,city2,rate2,array);
                            Descriptions sum = new Descriptions(site1,site2,site3,answer);

                            switch(answer)
                            {
                            case 1: time = time + 2;
                                    scost = scost + tcost1;
                                    sum.Description();
                                    array.add(site1);
                                    System.out.println("");
                            break;
                            case 2: time = time + 2;
                                    scost = scost + tcost2;
                                    sum.Description();
                                    array.add(site2);
                                    System.out.println("");
                            break;
                            case 3: time = time + 2;
                                    scost = scost + tcost3;
                                    sum.Description();
                                    array.add(site3);
                                    System.out.println("");
                            break;
                            case 4: time = time + 2;
                                    scost = scost + (rate2*25);
                                    food.Eat();
                            break;
                            case 5: time = time + 2;
                                    System.out.println("You rested for a couple of hours.");
                            break;
                            }

                            if(time == 22)
                            {
                                days2 = days2 - 1;
                                time = 10;
                            }

                            if(days2 == 0)
                            {
                                count++;

                                for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
                                {
                                System.out.println("Thank you for using the tourist simulator. You spent " + scost + " and visited " +array.get(i));
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-declaring your ArrayList every iteration of your loop.

Try declaring your ArrayList above your declaration of the Scanner.

**e.g.**

Move

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
```

To just above

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```